# increasing max connections on a single server (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, scale

I have a server with high cpu and ram, they are not getting hit hard.

I am trying to hit 4,000 concurrent connections.

I have done:

1) increase mysql max connections

2) update prefork settings in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>

    StartServers 100
    MinSpareServers 10
    MaxSpareServers 10
    ServerLimit 40000
    MaxClients 40000
    MaxRequestsPerChild 1000

</IfModule>
```

What other steps should can i take?

Answer (score 0):

Without (re)writing an entire guide on Apache and system tuning in general, a common set of changes would be:

1. mpm_worker
2. fastcgi php
3. php caching/acceleration